# How do auto-delete users that are blocked by access rules

Tags: 6, users

How do I actually get the system to delete a user that tries to sign up with a blocked E-mail? In Drupal 6, even when an E-mail is blocked via an access rule, the user can still register with that E-mail. The user exists in the system even though he's not allowed to login. This is cluttering up the user DB, is there a way to block the registration from taking place to being with or at least have the system delete such users automatically?